# How can I make node js synchronize?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I used promise as suggested but still I have a problem that I can console.log my array.

here is what I did:

```
exports.getData = function(request, response) {

    userEmail = request.body.user;

function delay(ms){ // takes amount of milliseconds
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){ // when the time is up
      resolve(); // change the promise to the fulfilled state
    }, ms);
  });
}

    Wish.find({userEmail}).exec( function(err, docs) {
        //console.log("docs "+docs);
        var wishArray = new Array();


            for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {
            if (docs[i].sub=='party') { 
                var id = docs[i].num;
                delay(100).then(function(){
                    Party.find({id}).exec(function(err, details) {
                      console.log("5");
                    wishArray.push(details);
                });
            });
            }  
        } 
    });
    delay(700).then(function(){
    console.log(wishArray);
});

}
```

I tried make the number of the second delay larger but it didn't work.
anyone has any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: you have 2 `console.log(wishArray);` the first one will work correctly

Comment: right the second one is not working I did that so I can see that the array is not empty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid logging untill wishArray is fully populated,  this way.

```
exports.getData = function(request, response) {
userEmail = request.body.user;

Wish.find({userEmail}).exec( function(err, docs) {
    console.log("docs "+docs);
    var wishArray = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++) {

        if (docs[i].sub=='party') {
            console.log("--------------------"); 
            var id = docs[i].num;
            Party.find({id}).exec(function(err, details) {
                wishArray.push(details);
                  if(wishArray.length == docs.length){
                      console.log(wishArray);
                  }

            });
        }  
    }
    console.log("***************************"); 

});
```

}

in many other complex use cases people used **array of deferred queries**. but your case is simple one you can catch hold of it just by length of array.

Comment: this will not wait. I suggest a promise().

Comment: @Iceman how do I use it so both function will work?

Comment: @user3488862 give me 20mins, and ill post an answer using promise. sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Iceman thanks! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Iceman   yes i'm here

Comment: I have edited my answer with full code. just in case , If you have misunderstood. it, I already said there is a promise method. but did not suggested it because it may be heavy.  I don't know what the hale , some jealous person has  downvoted me. as I never said this is perfect answer...

Comment: @enRaiser wow thanks!!! life saver!

Comment: @enRaiser :D no worries, I've upvoted you . user3488862 cheers.